# MySql: How do I sort a query by 2 specific categories and then by price?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have this table `prices`. Column `categoy` is type `enum` `['owner','tax','fees','misc']`.

```
+--------------+--------------------+------------------+
| id           | category           | price            |
+--------------+--------------------+------------------+
|          106 | tax                |             0.20 |
|          609 | owner              |            -0.49 |
|          609 | tax                |             1.20 |
|          609 | fees               |             0.10 |
|          106 | fees               |             2.20 |
|          106 | owner              |            -0.40 |
+--------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

I need to sort by having `tax` and `fees` at the top or `fees` and `tax`and those two sorted by lowest price first but sorted by id.

I want my result set to be

```
+--------------+--------------------+------------------+
| id           | category           | price            |
+--------------+--------------------+------------------+
|          106 | tax                |             0.20 |
|          106 | fees               |             2.20 |
|          106 | owner              |            -0.40 |
|          609 | fees               |             0.10 |
|          609 | tax                |             1.20 |
|          609 | owner              |            -0.49 |
+--------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

Ive tried different queries but can't get the correct answer. How can I do this?
Something like 
`order by id, field(category,'tax','fees'),price desc`

Comment: remove the `id` from the `order by` clause

Comment: can you please create a http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Change `field(category,'tax','fees')` to `field(category,'fees','tax') desc` and it should work

Comment: Order by id, category not in ('tax','fees'),-- or case when category not in... then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with CASE WHEN method

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN category IN ('tax','fees') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ASC, price ASC, id ASC
```

Ordering tax and fees first, others second, then orders by price ascending, also if same prices then orders by id in ascending order.

EDIT:

So you wish to be sorted by id, then tax and fees sorted first (and after that others), by price, then try this:

```
ORDER BY `id` ASC, (CASE WHEN category IN ('tax','fees') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ASC, price ASC
```

I've also tested the query and got your result:
[image: query order]

Answer (score 0):

if the enum is order as you need  you could use

```
select  id , category ,price   
from my_table  
order by id, category, price desc
```

otherwise you could use  fiedld()

```
select  id , category ,price   
from my_table  
order by id, field(category,'tax','fees', 'owner','misc'), price desc
```

or case

```
select  id , category ,price   
from my_table  
order by id, case when  category = 'tax' then 1 
                  when category  = 'fees' then 2 
                  when category  = 'owner' then 3 
                  when  category = 'misc' then 5 
                  else 5 end A, price desc
```